# Run automated Selenium Nightwatch.js tests in Docker Container with Jenkins CI

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins, gitlab-ci, nightwatch.js

My automated tests based on `Nightwatch-Cucumber` and `Nightwatch.js`. I've created a Dockerfile and push the builded [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/grme/nightwatch-chrome-firefox/) to Docker Cloud.

Currently my automated tests with `Nightwatch-Cucumber` and `Nightwatch.js` will be executed successfully over `GitLab CI` in my created Docker image/container on headless `Chrome`. Therefore I created a `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: "grme/nightwatch-chrome-firefox:0.0.1"

stages:
  - "chrome-tests"

before_script:
  - "npm install"
  - "npm install -y nightwatch-cucumber@7.1.10"
  - "npm install -y chromedriver@2.30.1"
  - "npm install -y geckodriver@1.7.1"
  - "npm install -y cucumber-html-reporter@2.0.3"
  - "npm install -y multiple-cucumber-html-reporter@0.2.0"

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

run-tests-on-chrome:
  stage: "chrome-tests"
  script:
    - "xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1600x1200x24' npm run test-chrome"
  only:
    - "master@xxx/e2e-web-tests"
```

And now I want to port this test execution to a `Jenkins CI`. So, I want to execute my tests in the same way as with the `GitLab CI`.

At first I want to use a local `Jenkins CI` instance to execute my tests. I want to create two jobs:

1. Execute the tests on push to master of test project (equivalent to the current `GitLab CI` solution)
2. Execute the tests by starting the manually over `Jenkins CI`
3. Execute the tests by a time trigger over `Jenkins CI`

I want the builds fail if tests are not passed and I want to create a `Cucumber` report after each execution with the `Cucumber Report Jenkins Plugin`.

My first idea was to create a shell script that starts the container and executes the tests in the container. But then I get no test results back to `Jenkins CI` or?

The procedure with `Nightwatch.js` is different to the Java implementations with **Selenium**. So, its my first time working with **Nightwatch.js**. The **Nightwatch.js** tests have to execute within the Docker container and the test result has to be returned to **Jenkins CI**.

Alternatively, I can run Jenkins within my created Docker container, but I want to separate it. The Jenkins should be a fix instance a only has to start the tests on Docker container.

But how can I realize it? How would you realize it with my setup?

Comment: Hi Martin, i've played a bit with your docker image grme/nightwatch-chrome-firefox:0.0.1 and i'm curious to see the content of the docker file for this version, could you please share that with us .

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure how Jenkins CI works, but I can run a docker container, with entrypoint `nightwatch` (so it runs nightwatch and then stops the container) from within Jenkins, and get the result as output. Simply `docker run [containername]` would do the trick. If you have junit.xml as output, you can cp it, even from the stopped container, with `docker cp [containername]:[absolute_path_to_file_in_container] [destination]`

There are also Jenkins plugins available to analyze that junit file, which can set the job status, and publish the results.